# How to make optimize ajax or request from cache

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have server from amazon with cloud and have around 20K visitor at a time, but the problem is, I introduced a section to my site , which load content depend upon the height of page.

e.g. if a page have 2000px height , it request around 40 post's , Its ok for small number of visitor but not good with more than 1000 visitor (at a particular time).

Its halt my server and crashed mysql when i activate it , So is there any way i can smoothly get post without loosing visitor ?

Then i request post in 5-5 group using

```
function sfpside_bar_post_request(sfpnumber_of_post) {
        iCountI = 1;
        numbverofrequest = Math.floor(sfpnumber_of_post / 3);
        remainderpost = sfpnumber_of_post % 3;
        spi = setInterval(function() {
            if (iCountI > numbverofrequest)
            {
                handle_sidepost(remainderpost,iCountI);
                clearInterval(spi);
            }else{
              handle_sidepost(3,iCountI);  
            }
            iCountI++;
        }, 1000);
    }
    function handle_sidepost(num_post,count) {
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        var data = {
            wp_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('sfp_forum_secret_no_one_knows_LATEST_SIDEBAR'); ?>',
            action: 'sfp_sidebar_random_sidebar',
            post_num: num_post,
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            'async': true,
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': ajaxurl,
            'data': data,
            'success': function(data)
            {
                var sidepost = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                sidepostcontent = '<div id="sidesfppost'+count+'">';
                for (icount = 0; icount < sidepost.length; icount++) {
                    sidepostcontent += '<div class="sidebar-one-half"><div class="post_img">';
                    sidepostcontent += sidepost[icount].image;
                    sidepostcontent += '</div><article><div class="sflike">';
                    sidepostcontent += sidepost[icount].like;
                    sidepostcontent += '</div><div class="conten_wrap left"><h2>';
                    sidepostcontent += sidepost[icount].title;
                    sidepostcontent += '</h2></div></article><div class="snippet-box"><div class="left"><p class="sfp_greybtn">';
                    sidepostcontent += sidepost[icount].greybutton;
                    sidepostcontent += '</p></div><div class="right">';
                    sidepostcontent += sidepost[icount].circle;
                    sidepostcontent += '</div></div></div>';
                }
                sidepostcontent += "</div>";
                jQuery("#sfppost_sidebar_extra_post").append(sidepostcontent);
                jQuery(function() {
                    jQuery("#sidesfppost"+count+" img.imgload").css("width", "54px");
                    jQuery("#sidesfppost"+count+" img.imgload").css("height", "55px");
                    jQuery("#sidesfppost"+count+" img.imgload").lazyload({
                        load: image_loaded_page,
                        effect: "fadeIn",
                        failure_limit: 10,
                        threshold: 200
                    });
                });
            },
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15"
        });
    }
```

But it still crashes mine MySql

The WP which i used to request post

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'sfp_sidebar_random_sidebar' && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_nonce'], 'sfp_forum_secret_no_one_knows_LATEST_SIDEBAR')):

        $args = array('posts_per_page' => $_POST['post_num'], 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'sfp_forum');
        $rand_posts = get_posts($args);
        $iCount = 0;
        $postdata = array();
        foreach ($rand_posts as $post_data) :
            setup_postdata($post_data);
            $postdata[$iCount]['image'] = get_post_home_picture($post_data->post_content, $post_data->ID, $post_data->post_title, $author_username, 'category-small-thumb', 275, 416, true, true);
            $postdata[$iCount]['like'] = sfp_like_disklike_arrows("poplr", $post_data->ID, true);
            $postdata[$iCount]['title'] = "<a href='" . get_permalink($post_data->ID) . "'>" . sfp_strip_content($post_data->post_title, 50) . "</a>";
            $postdata[$iCount]['greybutton'] = sfp_get_grey_button($post_data->ID, $post_data->post_title, true);
            $postdata[$iCount]['circle'] = sfp_home_postCircle($post_data->ID, $post_data->comment_count, true);
            $iCount++;
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo json_encode($postdata);
    endif;
    die;
```

Comment: What is the SQL that is being executed on each Ajax request?

Comment: ya i request every time from database

Comment: Yes, but what do you request each time. Above we just have the javascript running on the client with nothing on the actual sql that is being run each time.

Comment: @Kickstart I have updated the question with WP request post code

Comment: If there is an SQL issue it will be buried in one of the routines your code calls (probably get_posts() or get_post_home_picture() ). I would also be concerned about how often this is called (ie, I would presume that as you vary the number of posts displayed by page size that you are probably using continuous scrolling, and possibly have an issue with repeatedly checking for new posts depending on the screen size).

Comment: I know the facts that's why I want to manage all in a optimize way

Comment: Problem is that all we have to go on to help you is a tiny fraction of the code that could be causing the problem, and are missing the bits most likely to be causing the problem.

Comment: yup true , So i Create a 100 post json now my MySql is safe all the time i request from that json file now .. but still have issue with response

Answer (score 0):

I have little thought about `optimize ajax request`,

Here is my code:--

```
var oldSearchData = new Array();
function handle_sidepost(num_post,count)
{
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    var data = {
            wp_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('sfp_forum_secret_no_one_knows_LATEST_SIDEBAR'); ?>',
            action: 'sfp_sidebar_random_sidebar',
            post_num: num_post,
        };
    if(oldSearchData[num_post])
    {
        data = oldSearchData[num_post];
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            'async': true,
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': ajaxurl,
            'data': data,
            'success': function(data)
            {
                oldSearchData[num_post] = data;
                //do your action.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

you can save state in ajax array...

Hope it help you little....

Another solution is :- Use [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin...